# Ignore several decimals and retrieve numbers only in a string using regular expressions

Tags: regex

I want to retrieve only the numbers from a string:

```
'AB_123.456.334.443'
```

would like to get:

```
123456334443
```

Comment: What language is this written in?

Comment: Using regular expressions.

Comment: What I mean is, are you using a certain programming language, or do you want a general solution? The easiest solution is to get all matches and join them together, but how you do that depends on the language.

Comment: Looking for a general solution.  I've tried '(\.\d+)(\.\d+)(\.\d+)(\.\d+)' but the decimals are still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two approaches to this:

1. Use `\d+` , where `\d` is a digit (a character in the range 0-9), and + means several times. Then concatenate the result into a single string.
2. Use `\D+` to extract all non-digits from the string and replace with `""`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `\d`

For example in Java it would be something like this:

```
String s = "AB_123.456.334.443";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

// will print 123456334443
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.print(m.group());
}
```